# PHP static caching doesn't work

Tags: php, caching

I am new to PHP generally and caching and am trying to develop a Facebook share counter for Wordpress. As advised by a member here, since it's not optimum to make calls to the API and slow down the website each time, I decided to cache the results and went with the static method. Here's the code I am using.

```
function fb_cache($atts) {
    $url = $atts['url'];
    static $fb_cache = array();
    if (isset($fb_cache[$url])) {
    $fb_count = $fb_cache[$url];
    return $fb_count;   
    } else {
    $fb = json_decode( file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $url) );
    $fb_count = $fb->share->share_count; 
    $fb_cache[$url] = $fb_count;
    return $fb_count;
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work as the number keeps changing every few seconds and the API calls are thus being made each time. To use it as a plugin, I also have an instantiating code in the end.

```
static function get_instance() {
    static $instance = false;

    if ( ! $instance ) {
        $instance = new self;
    }

}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong. I apologize if it's a noob question and if I am using the wrong method altogether.

Comment: what type of cache do you use?

Comment: static I guess. I am totally new to this. Did a lot of reading and since I am on xampp right now and plan on getting a shared hosting, i am trying to keep it as simple as possible

Comment: define static cache ..

Comment: When you assign a variable a static value for some time so that it doesnt make calls to the db or in this case the funcction to make api calls each time the website or a page loads.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone. I found caching to text files the best option for me right now. If it seems to slow down the website in the future I am gonna try caching to a DB. Thanks for the advice @madalinivascu